# How to Convert Hash Back to Text

Tags: c#

I am using this to convert text to hash.

How should I convert the hash text to its original. It is needed to display the text.

**C#:**

```
private string HashPassword(string sText)
{
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sText);
Byte[] hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider().
               ComputeHash(data);
return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is symmetrical encryption, not hash.

Comment: assuming this is for a password best practice you should never display the user password, if they forget it then reset it and let them make a new one.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar He's hashing passwords.  Those really should be hashed, not encryped, and he really shouldn't be able to get the plaintext back out of them.

Comment: Oh, you’re hashing passwords? Don’t use SHA256. Especially not without salt. Use a password hash. bcrypt, scrypt, PBKDF2, etc.. (Well, maybe *you* aren’t the one hashing passwords. Maybe you’re trying to reverse the hash, so you don’t want a strong password hash. But that’s still hard.)

Comment: @Servy - true, if it is indeed for password, Ruby should just compare hashes.

Comment: Yes, already doing the same comparing. But just had to display . But got it. It cant.

Answer (score 12):

A hash is a one way process. Simple answer is you can't.

You can however generate tables of values and their hash equivalent and then go searching through those, they're known as rainbow tables, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) on Wikipedia, but depending on how complicated the input value was these become increasingly unfeasible.

Comment: Rainbow table is a little excessive for anything other than disaster recovery / hacking given the scenario being hinted at by the OPs code ;p

Comment: @Jack0x539 It also has no way of dealing with collisions, so you can never strictly *know* which of the possible collisions was the original value.

Comment: @Servy I was implying that the comment on the rainbow table was not relevant to the OPs question, given the code; I certainly wasn't saying do it.

Comment: @Jack0x539 Yeah, probably shouldn't have @ replied you with that comment; was more for Lloyd.

Comment: It was just a suggestion. I'd never go down that route myself. @Servy I hadn't actually considered collisions that's an interesting point.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot.  it is impossible.  That's actually the *point* of hashes like this.  They are a one way hash.  If you're able to get the plain text back from the hash *then the hash isn't doing its job*.